# Create a struct from a string using a macro

Tags: rust, macros

I have created a struct `Foo`. I now want to initialise that from a string using a macro, for example:

```rust
create_struct!("Foo");
```

`src/main.rs`:

```rust
pub struct Foo {
}


// Macro to initialize an instance of the struct with the given name
macro_rules! create_struct {($struct_name:literal) => {$struct_name {}}};

fn main() {let my_struct = create_struct!("Foo");}
```

Output on compilation:

```
error: macro expansion ignores token `{` and any following
  --> src/main.rs:8:26
   |
8  |             $struct_name {}
   |                          ^
...
14 |     let my_struct = create_struct!("Foo");
   |                     --------------------- caused by the macro expansion here
   |
   = note: the usage of `create_struct!` is likely invalid in expression context
```

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the end goal of creating a struct from the string type name? Considering that removing the two `"` would essentially work

Comment: Thanks - I want to initialize a struct from a string because I want the user to request that a task is run in the terminal by passing it as a string e.g. ./runme --task=Foo. Then I want to create the struct Foo e.g. let task = create_struct!("Foo"); task.produce_output();

Comment: If you get your macro working, then replacing `create_struct!("Foo")` with `create_struct!(name)` you'd most likely run into new issues. I'm assuming you're already using some command-line parser, so that likely has the feature you're looking for. But otherwise, it's a lot easier to define an `enum Task { Foo, Bar, Baz } `. Then use e.g. [`strum`](https://docs.rs/strum/latest/strum/) to derive [`EnumString`](https://docs.rs/strum/latest/strum/derive.EnumString.html), now that allows you to do `Task::from_str("Foo")`. Now you can easily match on `Task` or return an error, for an invalid `name`

Comment: Thanks - I will try that if all else fails, but I have dozens, potentially hundreds of tasks and  so it would be a bit cumbersome to have to maintain an enum, especially with a team of non-professional programmers (including myself) writing tasks, so I'm hoping my problem can be solved - but will try your suggestion if I do not get a solution.

Comment: I understand what you mean. However, having an enum is probably the most straightforward way to do what you need. Even if you had a `trait` that all your tasks implemented. Then besides rustdoc, then there's _really_ no way to obtain a set of all implementors, to be able to instantiate by name. You'd need to manage that manually. That can be done using e.g. [`inventory`](https://docs.rs/inventory/latest/inventory/index.html). However, you're trading adding 1 new variant to an enum, with having to write `submit!` for each type instead, which I personally consider worse in your case

Comment: If you are determined to go down this path, consider whether you could replace `create_struct!("Foo")` with `create_struct!(Foo)` and the use of `stringify!`. `create_struct` is only going to be able to work with literal strings at best, never with variables.

Comment: There is a fundamental misunderstanding here, a macro which is evaluated at *compile*-time can **never** change it's behaviour based on a value that the user put in at *run*-time. At best it can produce code that does, but then you'd usually just write the code itself instead.